# Classic ASP - how to get all T-SQL stored procedure rowsets

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, asp-classic, rowset

I have simple SQL stored procedure with several SELECT statements in it and want to extract this information like this:

```
Set cmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.command")
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "MyStoreProcedure"
cmd.ActiveConnection = objConnection
cmd.NamedParameters = True

cmd.Parameters.Append ...
cmd.Parameters.Append ...

Set rs = cmd.Execute()
```

How can I iterated over the rowsets in classic asp?

Comment: Your sp is return multiply rowsets? If yes - you can use `NextRecordset` method.

Comment: @VMV You can paste your comment as a answer and maybe link to the method in order to accept it and close the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need use `NextRecordset` method, see description here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677539(v=vs.85).aspx